# Endpoint when failing login Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I am developing a very basic application with Flask (and Flask-Login), and I have a problem when the user tries to login and fails.

If the user logs in correctly, the server returns the username. I have seen that it is possible to change the endpoint of a correct login using `app.config['USER_AFTER_LOGIN_ENDPOINT']`, so there is no complexity in that.
However, if the user fails and the login is not completed correctly, by default the server goes to `'/user/sign-in'`, and I haven't found any information about this case in the documentation.

Is it possible to change this behavior? If the user fails the login process, I am interested in returning a customized response of the server.

As a very basic example of the code:

```
app.config['USER_AFTER_LOGIN_ENDPOINT'] = 'signedin'

@app.route('/signedin', methods=['GET'])
def signedin():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return current_user.username
    else:
        return "nope"
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, I'd just do it manually for the sake of simplicity. Make the login page send a POST request to itself, then deal with that and redirect if needed.